# Routing with Symfony3 is not working

Tags: php, routes, http-status-code-404, yaml, symfony

I have red all the topics I could find here regarding routing problems with Symfony 3 but they didn't help me.
So my problem is that my controller is not getting accessed.
Here is my code:

**routing.yaml:**

```
app:
    path: /test
    defaults: {_controller: AppBundle:Lucky:number}
```

**workspace/test/src/AppBundle/Controller/LuckyController.php:**

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
class LuckyController extends Controller
{
    public function numberAction()
    {
        $number = rand(0, 1000);
        return new Response(
            '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
        );
    }
}
```

When calling: http://test.local/test
I get a 404 returned, and clearing the cache with **bin/console cache:clear** doesn't help.

Comment: Try running `bin/console debug:router` to see if your routing is even loaded.

Comment: The response is:
...
 app                        ANY      ANY      ANY    /test

Comment: Does http://test.local/app_dev.php/test or http://test.local/web/app_dev.php/test work? Are you sure the URL is correct?

Comment: test.local/web/app_dev.php/test -> same 404, test.local/app_dev.php/test -> works
Thank you for the help, but why I have to write a path like that? Why I can't just write test.local/test ????

Comment: Maybe your *.htaccess* file isn't working. Are you using Apache? Also note that the default *.htaccess* from symfony standard points to *app.php*, not *app_dev.php*. Are loading the routing in production too?

Comment: Yes I'm using Apache and found that video, which helps solving that path redirections: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1uQZC7_gsM But I'm still not sure if that's the right approach. Where is the benefit in using or not using the .htaccess provided by Symfony? I don't have any production system running yet, I'm just testing on dev for now.

Comment: You can develop without the "pretty URLs" just fine.

Comment: Is this still not working for you? If so, which operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are not so much comfortable with YML why not go for Annotation? Here could be what your Controller Class could look like using annotation:

```
    <?php
        namespace AppBundle\Controller;
        use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
        use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route; //<== BE SURE YOU IMPORTED THE "ROUTE" CLASS
        use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


        /**
         * Lucky controller.
         *
         * @Route("/")
         */
        class LuckyController extends Controller {


            /**
             *
             * @Route("/test", name="lucky_test")
             */
            public function numberAction() {
                $number = rand(0, 1000);
                return new Response(
                    '<html><body>Lucky number: '.$number.'</body></html>'
                );
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ty, I have already tried that, it didn't work, too. Looks like I have typed in the wron URL as you can see in the comments above. Further I don't like using annotations for routing, I want to keep that separated.

Comment: @user3741232    OK... keeping things separated is quite ideal ;-) Again;  I see nothing wrong with Your YML Routing either. However, assuming you are on Localhost, even with your YML Route, you should be able to access that page via: **http://localhost/doc_root/app_dev.php/test** unless you did something otherwise... perhaps in the htaccess or in the app_dev.php Files ???